# Couldn't find ArticlesSkill with ID=1 for Article with ID=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, form-for

I am trying to create an article.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :article_skill
  attr_accessible :articles_skill_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles_skill 
end

class ArticlesSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  has_many :articles

end
```

This is my form in the `article/new.html.erb`

```
 <%= article_form.fields_for :articles_skill, @article.articles_skill do |b|%>
    <label class="medium"><span class="red">*</span> Skill</label>
    <%= b.select :id, options_for_select(ArticlesSkill.all.collect{|m| [m.name, m.id]}) %>  
  <%end%>
```

Here the `article_form` is the builder for the `@article` form object.

If I try to save the `@article` object its showing this error.

```
Couldn't find ArticlesSkill with ID=1 for Article with ID=
```

Comment: What have you tried? Controller code? First two lines of the request (with the params sent)?

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days. Did a lot of searching.. it took going to the rails console and searching by the exception being thrown instead to make any progress with this.

Check out this answer on this question for why it's happening, and possible workarounds.
[Use rails nested model to *create* outer object and simultaneously *edit* existing nested object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346134/use-rails-nested-model-to-create-outer-object-and-simultaneously-edit-existi/12064875#12064875)

Be aware that using the first option presented here creates a security hole as described in http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2010-3933

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter in your `fields_for` call seems unnecessary. ActiveRecord is performing a lookup on the association `articles_skill` for `@article` when it reaches that param, but since the `@article` is new and has yet to be saved, it has no ID and triggers an error.

```
<%= article_form.fields_for :articles_skill do |b|%>
 <label class="medium"><span class="red">*</span> Skill</label>
 <%= b.select :id, options_for_select(ArticlesSkill.all.collect{|m| [m.name, m.id]}) %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest only a workaround. It works, but I don't like it - I want some out-of-the-box solution.

I assume you have a function:

> def articles_skill_params
>   params.require(:articles_skill).permit(:description, :name,
>   article_attributes: []) end

Add a function

```
def articles_skill_params2
  params.require(:articles_skill).permit(:description, :name)
end
```

Add another function:

```
def set_article

  article_id = articles_skill_params[:article_attributes][:id]

  article = Article.find(article_id)

  @articles_skill.articles << article

  @articles_skill.save

end
```

Change your ArticlesSkillController#create:

```
def create

    @articles_skill = ArticlesSkill.new(articles_skill_params2)
    set_article

    respond_to do |format|
      if @articles_skill.save
        format.html { redirect_to @articles_skill, notice: 'Article skill was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @articles_skill }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @articles_skill.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

As you can see, we simply exclude the nested attributes from the parent object creation (thus eliminating the error), then manually add them later.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want people to be able to select an existing skill you don't need nested attributes at all (that's useful for when you might want people to be able to create an article skill from the same form that creates an article). You just want to set `article_skill_id` to an existing value, so you can just do

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  ...
  <label class="medium"><span class="red">*</span> Skill</label>
  <%= f.select :article_skill_id, ArticlesSkill.all.collect{|m| [m.name, m.id]}) %>  
<% end %>
```