# Rails nested attributes creating has many through association, but want to set more data on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the three models set up like the below (incomplete for brevity):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :cases, through: :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :case
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :clients, through: :roles

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :clients
end
```

It's a simple `has_many through` association.  I've set up the models to accept nested attributes for the appropriate associations, and permitted the parameters properly in my controller.  I'm sending the below request body JSON to `POST /cases` which hits this method:

```
def create
  @case = Case.new(case_params)

  if @case.save
    render json: @case, root: 'case', status: :created, location: @case, serializer: CaseShowSerializer
  else
    render json: @case.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

And the JSON:

```
{
    "case": {
        "state": "CA",
        "clients_attributes": [
            {
                "first_name": "John",
                "last_name": "Doe",
                "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The case is created and the nested clients array are also created.  Rails automatically creates `Role` records for each `Client` in the array of JSON.  However, it only sets `case_id` and `client_id` (which associates the two).  I *ALSO* want to set other fields on the `Role` model that it creates.

How can this be done?

Edit:

Both answers below (Oct 1 2015, 12:50PM PST) will not work.  Using those answer's logic, a client can not have multiple roles (which is needed and explicitly defined in the model).

Example:

The roles *CAN NOT* nested inside of the case --

```
{
  "case": {
    "name": "test",
    "roles_attributes": [
      {
        "type": "Type 1",
        "client_attributes": {
          "name": "Client 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Type 2",
        "client_attributes": {
          "name": "Client 1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The JSON above will create the *SAME* client twice.  The Client with a name of "Client 1" has two roles, one of the roles type is "Type 1" the other is "Type 2".  The snippet above as suggested by the answer would create two clients and two roles.  It should create one client (since it's the same client but that client has multiple roles).

Comment: Favourited because you improved my knowledge, thank you :)

Comment: https://github.com/matisoffn/so32894063 here's an example.  Rails magically creates the association between case and client, but I want to be able to set data on the association it creates.  If I can't intervene and do that, then I want to be able to create them manually and have it set the case_id and client_id, and specify more fields that I want to set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting the `clients_attributes`, post the `roles_attributes` with the desired data for each role.

Each `role` in the `roles_attributes` can contain the nested `client` object.

When you do this, you might have trouble with saving a new role that references an existing `client`. Check [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6346134/398606) for the solution.

Comment: This won't work.  The reason is because if I do this, and one client has *TWO* roles, and I specify that client in each role object, it will create it twice.  I've went down this road.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to do this before is to define the various models' attributes as they are required. [I wrote an answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983131/rails-4-nested-attributes-and-has-many-through-associaton-in-a-form/21983998#21983998) a while back.

Your way is more concise (and better) than mine. However, you should be able to pass the data you need through it like I did:

```
{
    "case": {
        "state": "CA",
        "roles_attributes": [
           "name": "Admin",
           "client_attributes": [
               {
                   "first_name": "John",
                   "last_name": "Doe",
                   "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
               }
           ]
        ]
    }
}
```

If you didn't want to use JSON, and had to populate your data from an HTML form etc, you'd use the following:

```
#app/controllers/cases_controller.rb
class CasesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @case = Case.new
      @case.roles.build.build_client
   end

   def create
      @case = Case.new case_params
      @case.save
   end

   private

   def cases_params
      params.require(:case).permit(:state, roles_attributes: [:name, clients_attributes:[:first_name, :last_name, :email])
   end
end
```

You'd have to back this up with the appropriate model nested attributes:

```
#app/models/role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :case

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :clients, through: :roles

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
end
```

This would allow you to use the `fields_for` helper:

```
#app/views/cases/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @case do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :state %>
   <%= f.fields_for :roles do |role| %>
      <%= role.text_field :name %>
      <%= role.fields_for :client do |client| %>
         <%= client.text_field :first_name %>
         <%= client.text_field :last_name %>
         <%= client.email_field :email %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will not work!  Read my comment on the other answer.

Comment: Your JSON would not work.  Read your JSON then read the model associations.  You specify on the role a client_attributes array.  A role can only belong to one client, not multiple.

Comment: Trying this just throws an "association not found, are you sure clients is on Role?" something like that (because the association is *client*, not *clients*).  The reason is because it `belongs_to :client` so I can't pass an array, hence why your solution doesn't work and the JSON wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the candidness :) I've detailed how I'd approach it, whilst if it's wrong I don't expect you to accept the answer, I'll leave it up either as a discussion point or something to work from

Comment: Sorry for the reiteration.  I've spent many hours on this and already went down this road as well as other avenues still to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a github repo I could look at? I just took what I knew before and applied to this. If I see it in context maybe it will give me ability to test something out

Comment: I'll create an example app.

Comment: Made the README as descriptive as possible.